# webcrawling - article.find_elements_by_css_selector does not return all titles but a single element

Tags: python, selenium, syntax, web-crawler

I'm just trying to retrieve all the metadata info from the posting as highlighted in the image attached below. However, it is only returning a single metadata despite having used plural form below to retrieve all the elements and also ran a debug and it does return a list of webelements

```
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

website: https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=145&search_cat2=0

shown [image: Here]

I'm quite sure the for loop is should be do its job ...

[image: desired metadata to retrieve]

```
for category in article.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category'):
            print('    ', category.get_attribute('title'))
            print('EventTag categories:')
            # Listing EventTag
        for category in article.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category2'):
            print('    ', category.get_attribute('title'))
```

Comment: Why would you think `span.cat-category` is more than one element?  It's not, at least from that code snippet of HTML you are showing. Can you add the URL of that specific page to your original post?

Comment: @JD2775 thank you and apologies for forgetting to upload the website as well in the first place TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# removed loop since this is a single element
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.cat-category')
print('    ', element.get_attribute('title'))
print('EventTag categories:')
        # Listing EventTag

for category in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.cat-category2"):
    print('    ', category.get_attribute('title'))
```

Prints:

```
     海外
EventTag categories:
     景品あり
     有料あり
     広範囲
```

Your only issues were 1: The first element is a single element, so you dont loop over it, and 2: the indentation of your 2nd loop was incorrect